# How to connect directly to the ADB daemon via an Android

Tags: android, adb

I am looking to implement a Android virtual controller application. Most android games works with mobile gaming controllers but for certain games, this is not supported (Genshin, looking at you 0__0). Therefore, I need to implement a virtual controller that can take my game controller inputs and generate touch/swipe gestures at the coordinates of the on screen buttons (for the game). Something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Je0UoByNnmM

I cant use INJECT_EVENT permissions because its not a systems app. So alternatively, I'm exploring possibility of running an adb server as an Android service that my virtual controller app can connect to and issue input commands directly via "adb shell input ".

I am planning on using the WebADB repo, which has implemented the main communication protocol and message passing between the adb server/daemon here: https://github.com/yume-chan/ya-webadb/blob/3e5d18069928601aaa780e93807ab6dd8dc826ff/libraries/adb/src/daemon/transport.ts#L45

However, the WebADB implementation assumes is an external host/device connection, but I need to connect to the adb daemon running on the same device as my adb server. Does anyone here have any helpful suggestions on how to best approach this problem?

Comment: There was a similar question on [reddit.com/r/androiddev](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/13tpw5v/how_does_this_app_do_it/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which asked about how a different company did a similar idea.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, the recommended solution was to use Shizuku which implements the adb server/adb daemon connection, and then runs itself as a server so your application can use it to proxy adb shell commands. Gonna try it out